# alter the shape of a curve without affecting the height

Tags: functions, curves

I am using the following function with the intention of getting a skewed cosine the derivative of which decreases as x approaches 1.

A picture might explain better than I can: y = [(cos(0.5*pi*x)^1.5)*x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVWEs.jpg)

I would like the local maxima between 0 and 1 to be 1 for whatever value I give to the float coeficient and exponent. This would allow me to alter the shape of the curve without affecting the height of the curve

What I have been doing to address this previously is dividing by the local maxima between 0 and 1 everytime I alter the exponent (shape of the curve), however this is not very convenient. It seems like there ought to be a better way.

I thought perhaps computing the derivative might get the old brain gears going and lead me to an answer, but no luck so far.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very appreciative.

please excuse my rather unorthodox terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler polynomial with fractional exponent instead of a trig function. Function is taken in form $ y={x^2(1-x^m)} \tag1 $

We find critical and maximum values by differentiation

$$ y'(x)=0=2 x -(2+m)x ^{1+m},$$

$$\rightarrow x_{crit}= (\dfrac{2}{2+m})^{\frac{1}{m}}\tag2$$

Plug into (1) to evaluate $y_{max}$

$$ y_{max}= (\dfrac{2}{2+m})^{\frac{2}{m}} \dfrac {m}{2+m}  \tag3$$

To  normalize divide (1) maximum y-value at (3). Instead of unity introduce $A$ as maximum height for generality's sake.

All curves pass through $(0,0),(1,0)$ on x-axis:

$$y= A\dfrac{x^2(1-x^m)}{(\dfrac{2}{2+m})^{\frac{2}{m}} (\dfrac{m}{m+2})} \tag4$$

The constant height occurs at a variable $x$

$$x_{crit} =(\dfrac{2}{2+m})^{\frac{1}{m}} = f(m),\;y_{max}=A\quad \tag5$$

Graphed for  $ A=1, m= (2,4,5,8)$.

EDIT1:

$(\approx 0.61 <x_{crit} <1)$ for $(0<m<\infty)$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Narasimham. How do you derive the normalisation?

Comment: Computed x-critical value and $ y_{max}$ which was used for division/normalization. Hope it is clear.

Comment: @Stanley Appleton Trig function  $\sin \dfrac {\pi x}{2}$ can be used in place of $x$ but serves no particular advantage..

Comment: I think I understand. So xcrit should send the derivative to 0. But shouldn't the exponent of xcrit be 1/m?

Comment: Also, when cancelling higher powers of x to solve for xcrit, how did you know you weren't discarding the critical value between 0 and 1? I'm always a little unsure which solutions I am discarding when dividing by x.

Comment: Thanks.  That  was a typo, now corrected it. All else  okay

Comment: Typo, now corrected it.  Draw a graph of $_{xcrit}=f(m)$. The limit $0.61$ is tricky. Log differentiation, L' Hospital's Rule may be needed for exact evaluation.

Comment: Hope that was clear.